# How do I differentiate two different image components?

Tags: html, css, tags

Here's a bit of my HTML

```
<img class="backmain" src="tumblr%20purple%20veg.jpg">
```

I try putting `img`in my CSS to change some of the properties, but then this also changes one of my other images' as well. I've also tried putting the class `backmain` in but that doesn't work either!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an unique id to each image element or using `img.backmain` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `id="example"` and then change the css for `#example` that will work for you

Answer (score 0):

To change multiple objects at once, use 'class' (as you did). To pick up a unique object, use 'id'.

On your html add `id="name"` to set the object's unique id. Then, on your css, use `.name` when refering to a class name and `#name` when refering to an id name. Example:

```css
.backmain {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

#b {
  outline: 2px solid red;  
}
```

```html
<img id="a" class="backmain" src="http://i.imgur.com/p6sVAWS.png">
<img id="b" class="backmain" src="http://i.imgur.com/p6sVAWS.png">
<img id="c" class="backmain" src="http://i.imgur.com/p6sVAWS.png">
```